# IPTables causes conflict with Fail2Ban

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

OS: Ubuntu Server 18.04

Fail2ban: v0.10.2

I am trying to understand a bug with my Fail2ban installation (I believe from my own making). I have a cron job that populates iptables with a predefined list using:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s <ip address> -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s <ip address> -j DROP
etc
etc
```

At the beginning of this script, it runs:

`iptables -F INPUT` to flush the INPUT chain.
This cron job was present on the server before I installed Fail2ban to dynamically ban bad actors. However, I noticed I started getting a lot of notices stating that a particular IP was `already banned`. When I stopped the iptables cron job from running, this error disappeared, and has been runnning without any issues whatsoever.

My question is: What sort of conflict am I creating by running `iptables -F INPUT` while Fail2ban is still running? Shouldn't this command be fine since banned IPs are placed into their respective `f2b-<jail>` chain, or am I misunderstanding? If this iptables script needs to run, should I also do something with the Fail2ban database (purge, etc)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fail2ban must also place rules in the INPUT chain to call the chains it defines for each individual jail. By removing those, you are causing those rules to not apply, and the IP addresses that should be banned still get through, and fail2ban warns you about this by saying they were already banned.

You should not have any reason to flush the INPUT chain like this. Instead your cron job should create its own user-defined chain, and only add to the INPUT chain a rule to call that user-defined chain. Better yet, you should use an ipset, which has better performance and also can be atomically swapped when you want to change it. (And for that same reason you should have fail2ban use ipsets as well.)

Comment: fully correct answer! just a small amend: to be really concurrent safe if altering iptables one have to specify option -w (to wait for xtables lock) if supported (see man iptables), at least if INPUT chain gets modified/extended.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. I'm coming in to a place where the former Sys Admin is retiring. The iptables script is old, so I will work on updating it. I'll have to do some research on how to get fail2ban to use ipset.